# Animated Resize of UIToolbar Causes Background to be Clipped on iOS <5.1

Tags: ipad, animation, uitoolbar

I have implemented a custom split view controller which — in principle — works quite well.

There is, however one aspect that does **not** work was expected and that is the resize-animation of the toolbar on iOS prior to version 5.1 — if present:

After subclassing UIToolbar to override its `layoutSubviews` method, animating changes to the width of my main-content area causes the toolbar-items to move as expected. The background of the toolbar — however — does **not** animate as expected.

Instead, its width changes to the new value immediately, causing the background to be shown while increasing the width.

Here are what I deem the relevant parts of the code I use — all pretty standard stuff, as little magic/hackery as possible:

```
// From the implementation of my Split Layout View Class:
- (void)setAuxiliaryViewHidden:(BOOL)hide animated:(BOOL)animated completion:(void (^)(BOOL isFinished))completion
{
auxiliaryViewHidden_ = hide;
    if (!animated)
    {
        [self layoutSubviews];
        if (completion)
            completion(YES);

        return;
    }

    // I've tried it with and without UIViewAnimationOptionsLayoutSubviews -- didn't change anything...
    UIViewAnimationOptions easedRelayoutStartingFromCurrentState = UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:M_1_PI delay:0.0 options:easedRelayoutStartingFromCurrentState animations:^{
        [self layoutSubviews];
    } completion:completion];
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    // tedious layout work to calculate the frames for the main- and auxiliary-content views

    self.mainContentView.frame = mainContentFrame; // <= This currently has the toolbar, but...
    self.auxiliaryContentView.frame = auxiliaryContentFrame; // ...this one could contain one, as well.
}

// The complete implementation of my UIToolbar class:
@implementation AnimatableToolbar

static CGFloat sThresholdSelectorMargin = 30.;

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    // walk the subviews looking for the views that represent toolbar items 
    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews)
    {
        NSString *className = NSStringFromClass([subview class]);
        if (![className hasPrefix:@"UIToolbar"]) // not a toolbar item view
            continue;

        if (![subview isKindOfClass:[UIControl class]]) // some other private class we don't want to f**k around with…
            continue;

        CGRect frame = [subview frame];
        BOOL isLeftmostItem = frame.origin.x <= sThresholdSelectorMargin;
        if (isLeftmostItem)
        {
            subview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
            continue;
        }

        BOOL isRightmostItem = (CGRectGetMaxX(self.bounds) - CGRectGetMaxX(frame)) <= sThresholdSelectorMargin;
        if (!isRightmostItem)
        {
            subview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;

            continue;
        }

        subview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
    }
}

@end
```

I’ve set the class of the toolbar in InterfaceBuilder and I know for a fact, that this code gets called and, like I said, on iOS 5.1 everything works just fine.

I have to support iOS starting version 4.2, though…

Any help/hints as to what I’m missing are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, your approach can only work on iOS SDK > 5. Indeed, iOS SDK 5 introduced the possibility of manipulating the `UIToolbar` background in an explicit way (see [`setBackgroundImage:forToolbarPosition:barMetrics`](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and relative getter method).

In iOS SDK 4, an `UIToolbar` object has no `_UIToolbarBackground` subview, so you cannot move it around in your `layoutSubviews` implementation. To verify this, add a trace like this:

```
for (UIView *subview in self.subviews)
{
    NSLog(@"FOUND SUBVIEW: %@", [subview description]);
```

run the code on both iOS 4 and 5 and you will see what I mean.

All in all, the solution to your problem lays in handling the background in two different ways under iOS 4 and iOS 5. Specifically, on iOS 4 you might give the following approach a try:

1. add a subview to your custom `UIToolbar` that acts as a background view:

   `[toolbar insertSubview:backgroundView atIndex:0];`
2. set:

   `toolbar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];`

   so that the UIToolbar background color does not interfere;
3. in your `layoutSubviews` method animate around this background subview together with the others, like you are doing;

Of course, nothing prevents you from using this same background subview also for iOS 5, only thing you should beware is that at step 1, the subview should be inserted at index 1 (i.e, on top of the existing background).

Hope that this helps.

Comment: Shoot, I've forgotten to comment the layout subviews: I'm laying out my toolbar item views that way which would — otherwise — not animate smoothly but jump to their new positions as well.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand your comment, sorry... did my hint help?

Comment: My `layoutSubviews` is not intended to move the _background_ of the toolbar. It merely mitigates the problem that when setting the frame of the toolbar — even within a UIViewAnimation (block) — the toolbar items “jump” into their new locations. Inserting a statically rendered image as a subview on iOS <5.1 would be a somewhat acceptable workaround, although I hoped for a less hacky solution.

Comment: I didn't find the time testing your suggestion but since my layout hack works, I see no reason why inserting the subview shouldn't. There are no other answers that indicate there was an alternate way, so the bounty goes to you!

Answer (score 0):

Since I think this is going to be useful for someone else, I’ll just drop my solution here for reference:

Per sergio’s suggestion, I inserted an additional `UIImageView` into the view hierarchy. But since I wanted this to work with the default toolbar styling, I needed to jump trough a few hoops:

1. The image needed to be dynamically generated whenever the `tintColor` changed.
2. On iOS 5.0.x the toolbar background is an additional view.

To resolve this I ended up…

1. Implementing `+load` to set a static BOOL on whether I need to do anything. (Parses `-[UIDevice systemVersion]` for version prior to 5.1).
2. Adding a (lazily loaded) property for the image view `stretchableBackground`. The view will  be `nil`if my static flag is `NO`. Otherwise the view will be created having twice the width of `[UIScreen mainScreen]`, offset to the left by half that width and resizable in height and right margin and inserted into the toolbar at index 0.
3. Overriding `setTintColor:`. Whenever this happens, I call through to `super` and `__updateBackground`.
4. Implemented a method `__updateBackground` that:

   - When the toolbar responds to `backgroundImageForToolbarPosition:barMetrics:` get the first subview that is not our `stretchableBackground`. Use the `contents` property of that view’s layer to populate the `stretchableBackground`’s `image` property and return.
   - If the toolbar doesn’t respond to that selector,

     1. use `CGBitmapContextCreate()` to obtain a 32bit RGBA `CGContextRef` that is one pixel wide and as high as the toolbar multiplied by the screen’s scale. (Use kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast to work with the device RGB color space…)
     2. Translate the CTM by that height and scale it by scale/-scale to transition from UIKit to CG-Coordinates and draw the view’s layer into that context. (If you fail to do this, your image will always be transparent blank…)
     3. Create a UIImage from that context and set it as the `stretchableBackground`’s image.

Notice that this fix for iOS 5.0.x **will not work as expected** when using different background images for portrait and landscape or images that do not scale — although that can be tweaked by configuring the image view differently…